# Correctly styling CSS for mobile view?

Tags: html, css

How I'm presently styling all my elements:

```
#pandora {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63%;
  left: 51.5%;
  width: 9%;
}

#tidal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68%;
  left: 40.5%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

The thing is, this is me eyeballing my percentages, and I don't think this optimizes it for mobile (which I need). So, how should I properly style my elements?

Comment: You *definitely* don't want to be using `position: absolute` for every single one of your elements, and it's very unusual to require such arbitrary percentages. Obviously, what you want to end up with is something only you know, but what you likely want is to use `position: relative` along with `float`, `margin` and similar. You can use `media queries` to set breakpoints to apply different styles on mobile, but may benefit from a framework like Bootstrap (which does the hard work for you).

Comment: In what ways would Bootstrap handle all this?

Comment: Given you appear to want everything center-aligned, you can just use `text-align: center` for text elements and `margin: 0 auto` for the other elements :) And frameworks like Bootstrap divide your layout into a grid, where you specify how many columns you want your elements to take up. Think of it like building blocks with Lego. They handle all the margins and padding automatically, and can adjust things automatically for different screen sizes.

Comment: I've worked with Bootstrap before but don't really remember much. Could you add a comment to give me some starting code on how using Bootstrap for this would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the following link for practicing of bootstrap.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
```

For a responsive website, you need to learn the grid system of a bootstrap. It is the most important part of bootstrap.
Grid system makes your layout of system responsive.

But, there is a need of media queries also. Some times your internal data does not look good either it is in the responsive layout. For that time you need to use media queries for designing a better-looking website.

Following are some media queries, you can put your CSS code according to device size.

```
<style>

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

  }

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

}      

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

}

/* According to Mobile Orientation */
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

   /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

}
```

Comment: So how are you to combine media queries with Bootstrap Grid? Because Bootstrap Grid provides automatic re-sizing for different devices I think.

Comment: Hi @ex240 , When using Bootstrap it makes the responsive layout of the website. But sometimes there are some data like a paragraph or font, padding, margin etc. It needs other CSS code for looking good in other or small size devices so at that time use Media queries for making internal data responsive. And rest of the other layout Bootstrap makes it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use bootstrap grid system (col-md-*) to set your elements to scale between large & small screens. If you need any styling to be done only for mobile view or if you need to override the existing CSS properties for mobile the refer to media-queries.

**References:**

- Bootstrap Grid: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp
- Media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {  
   /* CSS for mobile view goes in this media query*/  
   #spotify-player {
     position: absolute;
     top: 75%;
     left: 34.5%;
   }
    
   #apple {
     position: absolute;
     top: 65.8%;
     left: 46%;
     width: 4%;
   }
}
```